# C# Select View from Oracle DB with LINQ

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I want to select a view from my oracle database with LINQ. I already imported the database with the help of Visual Studio, but i just cannot access the view via LINQ.

This is how i chose the view in the wizard:

[wizard selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27gTA.png)

Now i want to select the view like this:

```
var db= new ConfoEntities();
db.DView.toList();
```

but this does not work.

What i want to achieve is, to select the view like a table.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? In any case, C# is case-sensitive and `toList()` will throw a syntax error. Please post a code snippet that actually compiles and the full error message that you get. If an exception is thrown at runtime, please post the entire exception text, including the call stack, not just the exception message. You can do this by calling Exception.ToString()

Comment: I can't even compile the project because Visual Studio does not create a class for the view. For a table it would create a class, which I can select with db.exampletable.toList().

Comment: There's no `toList()` method. That's a typo. What EntitySets *are* defined in your context? Are you using the correct class, ie *is* ConfoEntities the context generated by the wizard? Did you include the `Model` namespace you show in the screenshot? *Please post the actual compile error*

Comment: [Project picture](https://imgur.com/hTFcpfE)

This is my project right now. You can see that in this example i selected a table instead of a view in the wizard because it created a class ADDRESS under Models - ConfoModel.edmx - ConfoModel.tt. 
You can see that i can select all rows of the table. 

The problem now is that Visual Studio does not create a class for my views, even when i select them in the wizard, only for tables.

Comment: You're not assigning the return type to a variable either.... `var data = db.ADDRESS...`

Comment: I think no one is understanding my question...

I have a Oracle database

In this database there are multiple tables.
In this database is also one view.

Now if I add the database with the help of VisualStudio i can make a LINQ query on one of the tables but not on the view. 

It looks like VisualStudio cannot create a view out of a database.

I know that i did not assigned a return type, it should only illustrate that i can access the ADDRESS table via LINQ but not the view.

Comment: Does the view have a primary key?

Comment: No it doesn't.

How would the SQL code look like if i want to create a primary key in a view ? (do you need more information about the view itself ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the columns of a view in an Oracle database are nullable if there is an UNION involved.

My SQL Code looked similar to this:

```
CREATE VIEW THEVIEW AS
SELECT column1 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column1 FROM table2
```

My solution was that I made the View with one Select in it, so without a UNION statement.

```
CREATE VIEW THEVIEW AS
SELECT column1 FROM table1
```

Then i imported the View with the help of the VS wizard.

After that I was able to access the View via LINQ.

The last thing I did was, I simply replaced the View with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW THEVIEW AS
SELECT column1 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column1 FROM table2
```

Now i have the View in my VS project and I can finally access it via LINQ.